# IIS 7.0 not properly handling static files

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, iis-7

I've been getting HTTP 500 errors for requests for static content, specifically `.css` and `.js`.  I started monitoring the HTTP requests and saw that the server is returning `text/html` when `css` or `js` is requested.

I'm running IIS 7.0, .NET 4.0, and Windows Server 2008.

All of the `MIME` settings are correct in IIS. The Handler Mapping looks correct as well:

```
Name = Static File
Path = *
State = Enabled
Path Type = File or Folder
Handler = StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule
Entry Type = Inherited
```

Also I have verified that the `StaticFileModule` is in the Modules, and checked that the `static.dll` is there in `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\static.dll`.

The only workaround I have been able to come up with is to hard-code into my sites `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="javascript" verb="*" path="*.js" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="css" verb="*" path="*.css" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="png" verb="*" path="*.png" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="bmp" verb="*" path="*.bmp" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="gif" verb="*" path="*.gif" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
        ....
    </system.webServer>
```

However, it should work without this...it has in the past and it currently does in other environments.

Comment: "it has in the past and it currently does in other environment" So what changed?

Comment: I wish I knew. The only two things that stand out to me are that the account which we run the app pool under, we had moved it around in the active directory a bit one day, but put everything back to the way it originally was. That and we also had a power outage last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the windows account which the application pool is running under needed to be added to the `Impersonate a client after authentication` local security policy.

Comment: Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment

Comment: where is local security policy?

Comment: Click start and type 'local security policy'

Comment: actually, nevermind, the solution proposed didn't work for me, so I shouldn't upvote

Comment: Altering the `web.config` file as I have in the Question didn't work?